# Rails on Rails taking it to the next level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, programming-languages, computer-science

For the past few months i've had the feeling that i reached a boundry in my knowledge of Ruby on Rails (RoR) development. I've developed large and small applications for both big/small clients and friends / hobby projects. I know how to develop these applications and it's beginning to feel a little bit tedious. I want to take my programming skills to the next level, me having a little experience with Javascript i enduldged myself in some good Javascript books and learned alot! But now i'm back stuck at the same RoR level that i've been for the past few months. and i want to get that knowledge boost i got from the Javascript books.

I really want to contribute to alot of open source projects but when i look at the source code i get the feeling that i dont know enough of the code and that i will become a irritating burdon to the main developer(s) of the project(s). This is just some uncertainty of mine but i dont want to tire/irritate other developers...

I feel stuck and i dont know what to do to up my own level. I try to read the source codes but often i get stuck with mainly the question "why are you doing this, and what are the benefits of it? And how does it work?". I know i want to up my knowledge of both ruby and rails but i dont know how to do this. In my time programming RoR it's been very difficult for me to pinpoint my "skill level" knowing i can always up my skills. So knowing this i started with some basic Ruby books: The well grounded Rubyist and Beginning Ruby. These were great books i learned some nifty little tricks but that's about it.

Do you guys recommend any resources and or books. I don't have alot of experience with other languages than Ruby / Javascript. But i really want to learn, i don't have a solid programming background because it mainly evolved from hobby to work. I want to contribute to open source projects and work and mainly learn from other great developers. I'm stuck and i don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few books:

- Eloquent Ruby
- Rails Anti Patterns
- Crafting Rails Applications

Then, armed with knowledge, you'll be able to read code (your first and good intuition): that's a great source of inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will start with these 3 books. the latter one looks very promissing :) thank you!

Comment: These books are a great start. The way to take it to the next level is to get better at Ruby, and OO programming in general. I would like to add Design Patterns in Ruby to this list.

Comment: @railsninja: I'll have a look, it's the same author as Eloquent Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of good material at [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) which is worth looking through. You can learn a lot about current practices, something doubly important when a lot of the Rails material out there is for 2.x or 3.0 and doesn't reflect the state of the art.

The best way to improve your skill is to find new challenges to exercise yourself. You'll need to work on general Ruby and general programming as well as improving your knowledge of the Rails framework.

Set aside time to read and understand the various APIs you're being exposed to. The more you know your toolbox, the less time you'll waste trying to do something that's already implemented. [APIDock](http://apidock.com/) is one of the many documentation aggregators out there for Ruby and Rails. As Ruby is generally quite readable, it's even educational to browse through the source for the libraries you use and see what methods are offered as well as any insight you might gain from observing how they're implemented. Often there are interesting use cases that are never fully documented but will serve you well when you need them.

There's a lot more to say, but really, it's a long journey. That's why people write things like [Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) as a counter-point to the "Teach Yourself X in 21 Days" books plague the industry.

Comment: Thanks for the tips about APIDock, i know the railscasts and i feel that most of the video tutorials are a little bit too easy for my taste. I will look into the suggested book! Thanks again :)